# Issue: Glib-Gobject-warning **: cannot register existing type 'GDKDisplayManager'

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt, raspberry-pi, gtk

I've designed a interface with pyqt and opencv python to my raspberry, so there's no problem when I run a basic test to open the camera  ( cv2.imshow('test',frame) this is too basic is just to check if my camera is working) and yeah the camera open successfully but the problem occurs when I try to open the camera within my interface created on pyqt5, because it launches a few errors but the main is 
   `Glib-Gobject-Warning **: cannot register existing type 'GDKDisplayManager'`

Full Error:

```
Glib-Gobject-Warning **: cannot register existing type 'GDKDisplayManager'
Glib-critical **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0 ' failed
Glib-Gobject-CRITICAL **:g_object_new: assertion 'G_TyPE_IS_OBJECT(Object_type)'fail
Glib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (null) pointer instance
Glib-GObject-CRTICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE(instance)'failed
Glib_GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'GdkDisplay'
Glib-critical **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0 ' failed
Glib-Gobject-CRITICAL **: g_type_register_static: assertion 'parent_Type > 0'failed
Glib-critical **: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0 ' failed
Glib-Gobject-CRITICAL **:g_object_new: assertion 'G_TyPE_IS_OBJECT(Object_type)'failed
```

This is the function which is opening the camera

```
def OpenCamera(self):
    self.setup_CameraSettings()       
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.CameraSource) # video capture source camera (Here webcam of laptop) 
    cap.set(3, self.Resolution_x) # set the resolution
    cap.set(4, self.Resolution_y)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_AUTOFOCUS, 0) # turn the autofocus off
    focus = self.Focus  # min: 0, max: 255, increment:5
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOCUS, focus)

    ret,frame = cap.read() # return a single frame in variable `frame`

    if ret== True:            
        cv2.imshow('Settings Test',frame)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows() 
    else:
        self.popUp_Message('Camera Unplugged')
```

This code is running successfully on my PC so the problem is not in the function, I think is about PyQt at my raspberry pi

Answer (score 9):

[PROBLEM SOLVED]

I am developing GUI with PyQt5.

I got error messages after running this code:

> (python3:2306): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 10:38:58.937: cannot register existing type 'GdkDisplayManager'
> (python3:2306): GLib-CRITICAL **: 10:38:58.938: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
> (python3:2306): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 10:38:58.939: g_object_new_with_properties: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_OBJECT (object_type)' failed

```
def SelectROI(self):

    #cv2.imshow("Select Region of Interest", self.browsed_img4)
    ImageToCrop = self.tmp_4.copy()
    

    r = cv2.selectROI(ImageToCrop)
     # Crop image

    imCrop = ImageToCrop[int(r[1]):int(r[1]+r[3]), int(r[0]):int(r[0]+r[2])]
```

The problem occurs when u are using different gtk version... For my case I was using gtk2 in QT configuration but in my machine I am using gtk3.

[Solution]

edit qt5ct.conf file

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/qt5ct/qt5ct.conf
# replace style=gtk2 with style=gtk3
ctrl+x y ENTER
```

Comment: same error, but i cant locate qt5ct.conf anywhere.   no results on: ~$ sudo find ~ -iname "*qt5ct*" -print  
any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, this solution did the trick ! The configuration file was `~/.config/qt5ct/qt5ct.conf`. But anyone should see where to find it when launching `qt5ct` from a terminal: `Configuration path: "/home/user/.config/qt5ct"`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error when attempting to execute `ipython2 --matplotlib=qt` on a Dell G7 17 7790 laptop running Ubuntu 18.04 with Python 2.7, python-qt4, python-pyqt5 and python-pyside installed.

Installing `python-qtpy` solved the problem in my case. Hope this works for you.